# NameError: global name 'qbObject' is not defined

Tags: python, flask, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm on FLASK and integrating QUickbook Oauth using [QUICKBOOK INTUIT WITH PYTHON](https://github.com/simonv3/quickbooks-python)

```
def QBConfig():
    qbObject = QuickBooks(
        consumer_key='qyprdgW*********1vZ5yEnwgNQsO',
        consumer_secret='csnHfPP***WDnA*********CIjzfb3MAb4GI',
        callback_url='http://0.0.0.0:10080/QBGetAccesstoken',
    )
    return qbObject


@app.route('/intuitOauth')
def intuitOauth():

    qbObject = QBConfig()
    authorize_url = qbObject.get_authorize_url()
    # will create a service, and further set up the qbObject.
    return redirect(authorize_url)


@app.route('/QBGetAccesstoken')
def QBGetAccesstoken():
    oauth_verifier = request.args.get('oauth_verifier')
    session = qbObject.get_access_tokens(oauth_verifier)
```

Here **intuitauth** function initialize qbObject which is object containing the  third party app key configuration.

**Quesion is : how could I access qbObject globally?**

When intuitauth gets success, callback url called (**QBGetAccesstoken**).
And here is the section where i'm getting error "**qbobject is not defined**.

The functions are not written in class. **qbobject objects might be destroy when callback function called**, Can anyone guess the exact issue or solution, how to pass the original object when callback function is called ( page is refresh when callback is calling).

I even tried to store object in session usking like `session['qbobj'] = qbObject` but unfortunately not worked.

I also tried to reinitialize the object in QBGetAccesstoken function like   `qbObject = QBConfig()`, returns the "None" error with "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A silly mistake I do to define variable globally. It works fine for below code.

```
qbObject = QuickBooks(
        consumer_key='qyprdgW*********1vZ5yEnwgNQsO',
        consumer_secret='csnHfPP***WDnA*********CIjzfb3MAb4GI',
        callback_url='http://0.0.0.0:10080/QBGetAccesstoken',
)



@app.route('/intuitOauth')
def intuitOauth():

    authorize_url = qbObject.get_authorize_url()
    # will create a service, and further set up the qbObject.
    return redirect(authorize_url)


@app.route('/QBGetAccesstoken')
def QBGetAccesstoken():
    oauth_verifier = request.args.get('oauth_verifier')
    session = qbObject.get_access_tokens(oauth_verifier)
```

During the defination, **remove the `qbObject` from function**